# Submitting Expo app bundle to Google play - "unsupported version of Play billing. Please upgrade to version 3 or newer"

Tags: android, expo

Please help - I have a problem with enabling billing permissions in my expo app (managed workflow). When i build app bundle `expo build:android -t app-bundle` and submit it to google, google said that too many permissions - all permissions were enabled, which is insane.
I removed all - added "permissions": [] to app.json, but after that google says that I have to enable billing permissions in order to add in-app purchases.

I've tried to specify "com.android.vending.BILLING" permission, but Google doesn't accept it - it says *We've detected this app uses an unsupported version of Play billing. Please upgrade to Billing Library version 3 or newer to publish this app.* Removing this permission helped to get red of the error, but google still doesn't allow to add any in-app product on google play, it says *'To add in-app products, you need to add the BILLING permission to your APK'*

I tried to add    `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.play.billingclient.version" android:value="3.1.0" />` to AndroidManifest.xml but it didn't help either

P.S "expo-in-app-purchases": "^13.1.0" package installed

Answer (score 1):

So,finally, I resolved it.
I updated Expo and expo cli to the latest version, fixed appeared issue with packages. Then I removed `expo-in-app-purchases` because it's not supported in managed workflow (!) and installed `react-native-purchases` instead, which is for RevenueCat plugin. Then started using `eas build` instead of `expo build` command, because `expo build` is not supported in the latest Expo SDK. But building were failing because of `android` folder from the previous expo version, I spent few days before I figured out that `android` folder should be removed. Also, i kept android permission in app.json:

```
    "android": {
      "package": "com.mycompany.myappname",
      "versionCode": 1,
      "permissions": ["com.android.vending.BILLING"]
    }
```

After that i was able to build app locally and in expo cloud! And google accepted it and allowed to start adding in app products! Magic!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to use

```
 implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:5.0.0"
```

and in your manifest should contain something like:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```